# A text-to-speech app for Android that reads my Twitter timeline and my Whatsapp when I'm driving

Tags: android, speech-synthesis, twitter, whatsapp

I know multiple text-to-speech applications but I'm looking for one that could **read my tweets and my whasapp when I'm driving**.

Other possibility is a Twitter client that implements TTS functionality like for example Pocket...but I would like to also read whatsapp.

Comment: Any luck with this software?